# Detect time since last user interaction with application

Tags: java, api, jakarta-ee, user-interaction

I'm currently programming an application which is supposed to **log out the current user after x minutes of inactivity**. I do realize that there's a few ways to implement this, such as setting a timestamp when the user navigates and such, and then checking if too much time has passed every now and then.

However, before (hopefully) re-inventing the wheel and adding additional complexivity to the application, **is there any native method to retrieve the time of last user interaction?** *(Preferably cross OS, but at least supporting Windows)*

Comment: You mean beyond the automatic session stuff already there? What else do you need? If this is JEE, what does the OS have to do with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HttpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval%28int%29)

Comment: Or configure it in the configuration file, which is likely a better option.

Answer (score 0):

there is no native method to do that. You will have to use the timestamp method.